# How to prevent comment moderation flood?

Tags: notifications, moderation

I'm a OS administrator rather than a WP administrator, and i found that one WordPress installation sends an email every single time a spammer tries to post a comment. This is flooding the email daemon and is almost as bad as allowing spam.

I think we could disable comment moderation notification emails, but we don't want to do that.

Is there a way that WordPress may limit the rate at which sends email moderation notifications? (Like, for example, one per hour).

Comment: Do you actually need the email, or would you just need to be notified that there are comments awaiting moderation? It might be possible with a plugin, but a small script to just give a count for comments awaiting moderation and comments in spam (if any) that runs every hour might be easier and more straight forward.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to start with an anti-spam strategy. The Automattic-maintained plugin [Akismet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/) does a pretty good job at this. As far as grouping emails, you may want to take a look at [Digest](https://wordpress.org/plugins/digest/) plugin.